# How can I use a multipage jQuery mobile document in a iOS Home Screen App?

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm using data-ajax="false" to link to a multipage document, as this is required in order to trigger a full page refresh:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

This works fine within the full iOS Safari.  But when I make the web app a Home Screen App, if you click on a link that has data-ajax="false", this will trigger the launch of the full Safari App, breaking the "full screen" appearance of my Home Screen App.

Is there any way to make a jQuery-mobile app that has a multipage document, that also can function as a fullscreen Home Screen App?

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a href="/Account/SignOut" data-icon="back" data-ajax="false" class="logout">Log Out</a></li>

$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
  $('.logout').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign("/Account/SignOut");
  });
});
```

This was a STUPID chase but after 10 hours we used this solution. It works great... but you shouldn't need this hack, Apple!

Comment: Thanks for this Hupperware. I used a more generalised version... instead of `"/Account/SignOut"`, use `this.href`. That will then work with any link that you give your chosen class to (in this case, `logout`, but you could use something more general).

Answer (score 0):

Does this plugin help? https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget